# Div inside SVG foreignObject loses its position in Mac Chrome

Tags: html, macos, css, google-chrome, svg

Div inside SVG foreignObject loses its position and not visible in **MAC Chrome** browser and mobile view.

I tried to run this `HTML5` SVG code in **MAC chrome** (54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)); but the DIV inside the  become invisible (or seems to be losing its position/jumping out from the SVG) when content in the DIV Overflows or scrollbar comes. However, it works perfectly in MAC Firefox and all browsers in Windows (except Mobile views).

Is it an issue regarding

1. viewport metadata?
2. div inside ForeignObject?
3. MAC chrome bug?
4. CSS? 
   How can we solve this?. Your help is much appreciated.

What I tried,

Test HTML file 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygz6x0mu6sfhkes/testsvg.html?dl=0

Found a similar bug in Webkit forum

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23113

**Head**

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

**Body**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1600 1200">


   <rect class="cls-a" x="568.13" y="103.99" width="409.76" height="350.53"  />
    <rect class="cls-b" x="602.86" y="159.55" width="340.31" height="350.28" rx="13.35" ry="13.35"/>
     <foreignObject class="chat-outer" x="602.86" y="159.55" width="340.31" height="300.28" rx="13.35" ry="13.35">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">      
        <div class="list-wrap" >        
         <div>
          <div class="list-content">
           <div class="list-row">
            <p  >Hi</p>
           </div>
           <div class="list-row">
            <p  >Hello</p>
           </div>
           <div class="list-row">
            <p >how are you?</p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </foreignObject>   
  </svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-content {
            height: 280px;
               padding: 0px 25px;
            background: #ffccbc;
               overflow: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;

     }
```

Comment: I just happened to check the same thing in Mac chrome(54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)) and it ran perfectly fine for me

Comment: @Sumit I have edited my question to include a dummy html file, could you plz open it in your Mac chrome https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygz6x0mu6sfhkes/testsvg.html?dl=0

Comment: It seems to have something to do with units, if you set absolute width and height attributes on the root svg node, then it works. Also, if you remove absolute heights in your CSS, then it works... (well it's not weirdly offset, but you still can't have the desired output).

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you its working, but when setting absolute with it will not be responsive. Do you think have any way to make it responsive?

Comment: Didn't had time to really dig into it, but it indeed sounds like a bug in chrome, probably due to them being the only ones following still-in-drafts SVG2 specs, while others follow SVG1.1 specs. Not sure if anything has changed in there, so maybe it's not even a bug...

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug, but if inline widths work you could use JavaScript to set these based on window width? Not ideal, but if it works... (Doesn't warrant it's own answer, but not enough rep to comment).

Comment: Try wrapping the contents of the foreignObject in a `<body>` element. I.e. `<foreignObject><body><div>...</div></body></foreignObject>`. I have seen layout issues before that have been resolved using that method.

Answer (score 2):

We've just had a similar issue and managed to fix it by setting the overflow to visible on the foreignObject.